# Spring Tool Suite Maven project error in pom.xml at xsi:schemaLocation

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I just started my first maven project, but got error at the very first line of pom.xml file at the xsi:schemaLocation part.

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Demo Course API</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The first few lines of error description are

```
Failure to transfer com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not 
 transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was 
 cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.
```

I just copied it from the spring getting started guides but still got the error.don't know what to do.
My mvn -v is  3.5.2

Comment: First remove the maven-resources-plugin definition cause spring boot already defines a version correctly...apart from that have you run that on plain command line? Can you show a full log output ? Do you have a proxy/firewall in between ?

Answer (score 1):

There is incompatibilities between the version of M2E and the version 3.1.2 of the maven-jar-plugin.

Until the problem is solved by the development teams of M2E or maven-jar-plugins, you have to add in your pom.xml file the following line in order to solve this issue:

```
</project>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including this dependency in your pom.xml and check:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: included the above dependency still no luck :( Now the error description says :  Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will 
  not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: You may have to configure the local repository for maven. Follow https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: May i know why please.. i dont quite understand.

Comment: The dependencies mentioned in  pom.xml will first be searched in the local repository. Hence it should be configured properly. There should be .m2 folder in your user directory some where in the program files. If not try and create one.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the error description helped a lot in solving the above problem.
The error count was 53.

First as stated by @Duho adding the jackson dependency helped in reducing some error, now the error count reduced to 35.
Then the error was in the hibernate validator dependency, i fixed this by adding the hibernate validator dependency.
Dependencies can be added by right clicking the project-->Maven-->Add Dependency  .

Then i found out that maven downloaded some incompleted files from central repository to local repository, the download was incomplete. So, i deleted all   files with ".lastUpdated" extension from Users/'myName'/.m2/repository folder.

Then by updating the project from right click-->Maven-->Update Project helped in solving all the errors.

It worked for me.. hope this works for anyone with the same problem.